# Error: Cannot find module 'D:\next\dist\bin\next' when running npm run dev on a Next project

Tags: node.js, next.js, npm-install, npm-start

Trying to setup my dev environment on a new PC and I get this error when running `npm run dev`

[image]

Been trying to search for an answer for an hour now but can't find a solution.

I've tried deleting node-modules and package-lock.json and running `npm install` again. It didn't work.

Node version is v18.4.0

Any ideas?

Comment: The project I was trying to run was an existing project.
If I create a next app from scratch I can run it fine.

Comment: I have the same problem, so you recommend me better to create one from scratch and then copy and paste all the files into it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.
The problem was the folder name "Will & Skill". Changing it to "WillAndSkill" makes it work.

Comment: LOL... I did the same thing and I banged my head figuring out what was an issue until I found the solution here. Thanks..

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue without special letters in the path.
A minute ago It was working 

Comment: Thank you! I deleted node_modules, then install it again. And it works fine!

Answer (score 1):

If any special character is there anywhere in the path of your code base folder then it is creating the issue. I simply changed the location of my code base in my system and it started working.